# How to alternate two always blocks?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to design a simple Verilog code, which contains two always blocks, executing alternatively, like handshake. I want to use two flags, do_A and do_B to control the two blocks, block_A and block_B. The expected result must be ABABAB... Is there a way to correct the following code? Thanks for helping me.

```
    module tb;
    reg clock, reset, do_A, do_B;

    initial begin clock = 0; reset = 0; #50; reset = 150; #50; reset = 0; end
    always #50 clock = ~clock;

    always @(posedge clock) begin: block_A
        if (reset) do_B <= 0;
        else if (do_A) begin
            do_B <= 0;
            $display("A");
        end 
    end

    always @(posedge clock) begin:block_B
        if (reset) do_A <= 1;
        else if (do_B) begin
            do_A <= 0;
            $display("B");
        end 
    end
endmodule
```

Thanks Vesiliy, the following codes work well for the desired results.

```
always @(posedge clock) begin: Block_A
        if (reset) do_B = 0;
        else if (do_A) begin
            do_B = 0;
            $display("A");
        end 
        else do_B <= 1;
    end

    always @(posedge clock) begin:Block_B
        if (reset) do_A = 1;
        else if (do_B) begin
            do_A = 1;
            $display("B");
        end 
        else do_A <= 0;
```

It seems to be weird, but works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `reset = 150;` looks strange (typo?). It works in this context, though.

You have another typo in the first sequential `always` - what you (seemingly) meant to write is:

```
else if (do_A) begin
    do_B <= 1;
    $display("A");
end
```

However, I believe that your main issue here is that you do not have `else` (default) clauses in your sequential `always` blocks.

Look at this block (for example):

```
always @(posedge clock) begin:block_B
    if (reset) do_A <= 1;
    else if (do_B) begin
        do_A <= 0;
        $display("B");
    end 
end
```

After the reset deasserted `do_A = 1`; then, assuming that you fixed the previous typo, `do_B` will become 1 which will lead to `do_A` becoming 0. After this state is reached, `do_A` will be stuck at 0 until you reset everything.

The following addition should fix this (the same for the first `always` block):

```
always @(posedge clock) begin:block_B
    if (reset) do_A <= 1;
    else if (do_B) begin
        do_A <= 0;
        $display("B");
    end
    else do_A <= 1; 
end
```

I believe that your code with the above  fixes will work, however, the right way to describe this functionality is to implement a (simple) state-machine with 2 states. Google it.